# How can I separate this type of date and time data in Excel?

Tags: r, excel

How can I separate this type of date and time in excel "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM" or R?

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, convert to `POSIXct` class and then use `as.Date` to get the Date part and `format` to return the time part

```
df1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df1$datetime, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$datetime)
df1$time <- format(df1$datetime, "%H:%M:%S")
```